# ByteBuffer to byte array

Tags: java, arrays, bytebuffer

I have a ByteBuffer, and I need to add its content to a POST request in order to remotely display the image which represents; but I can't figure it out how to do it.

Doing this doesn't work:

```
byteBuffer.array()
```

I have tried to convert it to an array of bytes, but it didn't work because the image wasn't showing properly:

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[byteBuffer.remaining()];
frame.duplicate().get(byteArray);
HttpResponse response = null;
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL);
post.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(byteArray));
```

Also I've think about converting it to an image and get its array of bytes but I don't know how to do it and if it would work...

Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: `byteBuffer.array()` doesn't work? That's quite a claim.

Comment: No, byteBuffer.array() does not form the image correctly, and if I debug the app the result of doing so is an array in which each element is a 0 value...

Comment: Then either you haven't read anything into it or you haven't debugged cirrextly.

Comment: @svprdga Show us how you populate the byte buffer. Chances are, the error is there.

Comment: @EJP: From the documentation of ByteBuffer.array(): "Returns the byte array which this buffer is based on, if there is one", maybe my ByteBuffer has been made in some other way....??

Comment: @Duncan: I don't know how the ByteBuffer is populated, it comes from a compiled JNI library...

Comment: so how do you know the image that will appear if you don't know how the ByteBuffer is populated ?

Comment: The image is a frame from a webcam. This is the library: https://github.com/saki4510t/UVCCamera

Answer (score 5):

```
private static byte[] getByteArrayFromByteBuffer(ByteBuffer byteBuffer) {
    byte[] bytesArray = new byte[byteBuffer.remaining()];
    byteBuffer.get(bytesArray, 0, bytesArray.length);
    return bytesArray;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A ByteBuffer created with `allocate` (not necessarily `allocateDirect`) should have a backing array, check with `hasArray()` / `isDirect()`.

```
byteBuffer.flip();  // Sets limit to current write position.
int n = byteBuffer.limit();
byteBuffer.rewind(); // Already done by flip I think.
byte[] data = new byte[n];
byteBuffer.get(data);
```

Comment: hasArray() returns false. I have tried your code, byteBuffer.limit() returns 0 and the final data array has 0 lenght...